# How to Display Alert View continuously in iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, uialertview

I'm working in a scenario in which whenever the internet connection is lost I have to display an  alert view continuously until the user switch on the internet. Even if ok button in the alert view is pressed again the alert view has to be shown. Only if internet connections are available the alert should not be shown. Until that it has to be shown. How to do this?

Comment: Why not just present a new `UIWindow` with an `UIView` on it that tells the user the internet is down.

Comment: that is an annoying user experience, please tell me which application will do such thing, I won't install it ever in my life.

Comment: @holex +1, I agree- this is a poor design from the start. You should instead consider what the user *can* do without an internet connection and program to it (perhaps creating an offline cache of some sort, an initial plist/data file/etc as a seed, etc). After all, you're writing a smart phone app, not a webpage.

Comment: @JRG-Developer, yes, it should teach to every developer as the very first omnipotent rule of this profession: the application must _serve_ the users, not _control_ them.

Comment: Thank you for down votes :( by the way this was client's requirement.

Comment: @Chan Maybe you should advise the client of this UX problem then ;-)

Comment: @Nick I said it already. As for first time internet is must for the app to load the datas dynamically and save it in local db. Later if there is no connection also from local db i have to display it.

Answer (score 0):

Implement the `UIAlertViewDelegate` and try something like this. This will work fine.

```
UIAlertView *newmsg = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Message"
                                                          message:@"Internet Connection Lost"
                                                         delegate:self
                                                cancelButtonTitle:@"Ok"
                                                otherButtonTitles:nil];
        [newmsg show];
```

And if the user presses Ok and you want to show alert again on that click, use this:

```
- (void)alertView:(UIAlertView *)alertView clickedButtonAtIndex:(NSInteger)buttonIndex
{
    //write same alert code as above.
}
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

That is very bad user experience, however if it is really what you want they you could fire of a NSNotification when the internet is available again, and dismiss the alert then.

Also, if you don't want to dismiss the alert until the internet connection is available again, then what is the point in having the OK button - very bad user experience again, as they will think there is something wrong with the app.